# Keyboard low resolution

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I have an iPad project that i've been wanting to add an iPhone part to it.
So I've added a target and added a new Storyboard, but when I run the app and pressing a textfield, the keyboard looks strange. As if the resolution is low.

The left one is how it looks and the right one is how I want it to look:
[image]

Anyone has any clue? Thanks

Comment: I don't see any difference, the only the difference is Apple notes shows capital alphabets whereas your app shows small alphabets. And also the background color of Apple notes is the gray color, in your case its white.

Comment: What device is that? Have you set the correct launch images? It looks as though the whole app is zoomed.

Comment: Imad - I've edited the photos so it would be easier to see the diff.
James - You're right, i didn't see that until now. I have no idea why it looks zoomed. The device is the same for both (iPhone7 plus)

Comment: Check your launch images, if you don't have the correct size for the device the app will zoom.

Comment: It worked! Thanks James! Post your answer so I could accept it...

Comment: You could post your own answer with how you fixed it. I was just pointing you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Special thanks to James.P (from the comments above) for a great solution.

Apparently, this happens when one doesn't use any LaunchImages at all.
Just make sure to use LaunchImages correctly and it should be solved.